# Script failing when parenthesis in folder name

Tags: powershell

I am trying to structure the script so it can be ran in any directory, with the user only having to change the `$location` (or select one in future with a prompt) and all other paths being set by variables:

```
$location = "C:\\Scripts\\Script_Temp\(1\)"

Set-Location $location

$folder1 = "$location\\Folder1"
$folder2 = "$location\\Folder2"

$fol1_cont = Get-ChildItem "$folder1" -File
$fol2_cont = Get-ChildItem "$folder2" -File

$dupfolsexist = (Test-Path -LiteralPath $folder1\\Duplicates) -and (Test-Path -LiteralPath $folder2\\Duplicates)
$duplicates = (Compare-Object -Property Name -ReferenceObject $fol1_cont -DifferenceObject $fol2_cont -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent)

cls;sleep 1

if (!($duplicates)) { Write-Host "no duplicates" }

if ($duplicates) {
    if (!($dupfolsexist)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$folder1\\Duplicates\\Hashes Match", "$folder2\\Duplicates\\Hashes Match" | Out-Null
    }

    foreach ($file in $duplicates) {
        Move-Item $folder1\\$($file.Name) -Destination $folder1\\Duplicates
        Move-Item $folder2\\$($file.Name) -Destination $folder2\\Duplicates
    }
}
$hash1 = Get-FileHash -Path $folder1\\Duplicates\\*.*
$hash2 = Get-FileHash -Path $folder2\\Duplicates\\*.*

for ($i=0; $i -lt $hash1.Count; $i++) {
    if ($hash1.Hash[$i] -eq $hash2.Hash[$i]) {
        $filestomove = $hash1.Path[$i]-replace ("$folder1\\Duplicates\\",'')
        Write-Host "File hashes are the same "-NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green;
        Write-Host ">> " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow;
        $filestomove;
        Move-Item $folder1\\Duplicates\\$filestomove -Destination "$folder1\\Duplicates\\Hashes Match";
        Move-Item $folder2\\Duplicates\\$filestomove -Destination "$folder2\\Duplicates\\Hashes Match"
    } else {
        Write-Host "File hashes are different " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Red;
        Write-Host ">> " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow;
        $hash1.Path[$i] -replace ("$folder1\\Duplicates\\",'')
    }
}
```

There's probably a better way to do the whole thing!! But for now I'm just trying to find a way around where a folder name contains ( and ). The script works as expected when parenthesis aren't in the folder name.

Errors I'm getting:

without double backslashes in `$location`:

> Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Scripts\Script_Temp\Folder1\Duplicates\C:\Scripts\Script_Temp\Folder1\Duplicates\Test File 01.txt' because it does not exist.

with double backslash, none before ( or ) in `$location`

> Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Scripts\Script_Temp(1)\Folder1\Duplicates\C:\Scripts\Script_Temp(1)\Folder1\Duplicates\Test File 02.txt' because it does not exist.

with double backslashes and \ before () in `$location`

> Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Scripts\Script_Temp(1)\Folder2\Test File 03.txt' because it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you are seeing is that you are using a non-escaped string in a RegEx (Regular Expression) match & replace. The `-replace` operator performs a RegEx match against the string you build, for example here:

```
$filestomove = $hash1.Path[$i]-replace ("$folder1\\Duplicates\\",'')
```

In regular expressions there are a few reserved characters, such as parenthesis, brackets, and the backslash. You have manually accounted for the backslash, but other characters can mess with your match. A better way would be to use the `[regex]::escape()` method. Something like this:

```
$filestomove = $hash1.Path[$i] -replace [regex]::escape("$folder1\Duplicates\"),''
```

Comment: Many thanks this resolved it. I removed the \\ from all places in the script,added the regex escape where you mentioned and also later after the other -replace. I didn't realise its only required in certain places so thanks for the explanation!